# Form inline not really inline with label, text input and calendar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to write a form inline that has a labe, a text input and a calendar icon at the end. However, it is not being inline. In a first line the label renders and then below in another line the text input and the calendar icon. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is the html part:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/something" class="form-inline form" id="id29">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="id30">View Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input id="id30" value="2014-10-01" name="31" type="text" class="text form-control input-sm">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: why do you keep editing the code in your question? Especially after I gave you the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your divs and spans were a little out of whack. The easiest way to do Bootstrap until you have it memorized is to copy their code and replace their parts with yours :)

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/something" class="form-inline form" id="id29">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="id30">View Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="id30" value="2014-10-01" name="31" type="text" class="text form-control input-sm">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can save yourself the additional input-group div and just add it to the from-group div .. http://www.bootply.com/WHmcisMvd7 <div class="form-group input-group">

Comment: Sorry, I rollbacked the question. Actually..I have to say that I tried with your exact html and I have the same problem. Then I noticed in your bootply you were using latest Bootrrap and I was using a 3.0.x. I have just updated to latest...and boom, problem fixed!

Comment: Glad it's working! The Bootply was from Birgit, not me. Please mark this as solved.

Comment: @BirgitMartinelle No, please don't do that. See https://github.com/twbs/bootlint/blob/13a26567895d59965114133c9894f3cc269671bf/src/bootlint.js#L397